# Community topics at meta

Tags: discussion, community

*{note that meta was posted here since not able to post (steady error) in eta area, may the moderators pardon the additional work arising from it and may it be of benefit anyway for all your welfare}*

Of course, although generously invited, it's all your community here and some will ever be just "itching" guests, so it should be seen just as a "good encouragement", not at all a demand.

It would be good if the community tries to create areas for devotion to the tripple Gems and for instructions, greeting, welcome...

My person thought that you would be able to dedicate possible one topic here as "Welcome and introduction" topic, where user could introduce themselves to the community and welcomes could be posted in the comments.

And another topic, good to introduce, would be either a devotion topic or a Uposatha-Observance topic. Given that it is fulmoon Uposatha, even a perfect day today. If wished, of course, my person would help in situating and instructing to such which should not limit anyones possibilities to do merits and give all a very proper touch here.

To make things different as used to, better and a good sample for good for many, if wished so, is of course your choice.

*(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks or entertainment but as means toward release and encouragement to give the causes for such.)*

Comment: Rev, Johann, Will be down voted soon, saying this is not the correct place for this (no matter the issues are). And there are few people around who are kind of followers to a particular person, and no matter lie he says he it get upvoted. Or he has some fake accounts and keep upvoting all down votes ( I know there's a method in stackover flow to detect this, but it just happened few hours ago ). I felt like leaving the this community just because from the beginning when considerable answer is given its down voted, just because he doesn't know about it and asking for references.

Comment: And now even the questions get down voted just because the questions are harming his or their perception. I'm not talking about all, there are many people who really help to grow the community and help us to grow in this, but very few people who thinks they are the top wise person in the earth and try to overrule. If he is the top wise, what he is doing here with out go and attain nibbana. Really worrying on this Buddhism community.

Comment: Anyway this 100% complying with Buddha's dhamma. We can't expect the things as we want it to be, and also Dhamma is so complex to understand by everyone. And specially when everyone in the world thinks this is the Real Dhamma there's a doubt. Because according to Buddha only very few can understand Dhamma. This. To all my wish is to found the real dhamma one day may be this birth or next birth and attain nibbana. The time has come and the real Dhamma has started revealing now. (I'm not an expert or I'm not a Guru) Dhamma is only the Guru in this world.
Sabbe Satta Bhawanthi Sukhi Thatta..!

Comment: Upasaka @follower . Once a wise monk was asked why they do not remove disturbing people from the monastery and he answered: "They are actually the best teachers". Yet of course for someone new and not firm it will cut of any foundation. Whether one likes to make merits or is up after gain, try to let the Gems [shine like the moon](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn16/sn16.003.sang_en.html) and dont forget to seek refuge on secure places after having been out to give those able a possibility to make merits. Be always clear that dwelling under wrong view for the most.

Comment: Upasaka @follower could make an answer to the topic anyway, if he likes to try to make a good scarifies. And of course, like* all* others, he is always welcome [here](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=forum). if missing space for fundamental things on BSE and to bring back what helps BSE and many if wishing, out of compassion.

Comment: It seems good place. Let's see. Stackoverflow is very good for the wise people. This work any other subject but not the Buddhism, as it's something only be realised to the wise and paramita-completed people. That's why everyone couldn't got Nibbana even when they listen to Buddha those days. Let's pray for some of the people who think they are wise. (Please don't consider this as an offensive statement, i really meant this)
With Metta..!

Comment: Smart is not wise, just knowing is not really panna. It works because it is made for increasing stacks, but Dhamm-Vinaya actually works the other way around, is not a place to feed and eat together, but to sacrifies, Upasaka @follower .  So certain things are needed to make differently, not for trade and exchange. A place devoted to give into the Juwels is a place where one gains really Dhamma and liberation. Therefore the introduction and place to take refuge suggestion as to make a different that does not harm anybody but helps a lot.

Comment: @SamanaJohann - I do not mean to at all rude, but it may help you to understand the responses you receive if you realise that your language is almost impenetrable. I often do not know what you're saying and cannot reply even if I wished to do so. Just a note.

Comment: What does Nyom think? What is better, to want others to come down to them or to try to get up to them? Pulling in as householder, or leaving ones home fist?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are able to post on [the Meta site](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/), now that you're using a registered account.

Another place, which SE has provided for this type of conversation, is [the site's main Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism).

The [help  topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) says,

> **What is chat?**
>
> All sites have a real time web chat component, or as we like to call it, the "third place".
>
> > [The third place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place) is a term used in the concept of community building to refer to social surroundings separate from the two usual social environments of home and the workplace. In his influential book The Great Good Place, Ray Oldenburg argues that third places are important for civil society, democracy, civic engagement, and establishing feelings of a sense of place.
> >
> > Most needed are those ‘third places’ which lend a public balance to the increased privatization of home life. Third places are nothing more than informal public gathering places. The phrase ‘third places’ derives from considering our homes to be the ‘first’ places in our lives, and our work places the ‘second.’

On this site the chat room has been rarely used until now -- but users on other SE sites use their chat rooms daily, e.g. for greetings and personal conversations -- as well as topics of mutual interest e.g. related to the main site.

It can help, to get to know other users as people -- a sense of "community" just as you said.

Meta is slightly formal e.g. each page as a "topic" defined by the original post.

Chat is more informal, with posts just displayed chronologically.

Those aren't available to completely-new users though -- people need a small minimum of "reputation" to post on Chat or Meta (I assume that acts partly a measure to help avoid new/anonymous users making unwanted or inappropriate posts).

Comment: It's actually something formal, practice and the mentioned, and even not used now, Nyom Chris, maybe you like to give it a try since meta is actually given for such and can be used also in this way. Chat is something total not proper, it's not a gamer or what ever place and placed like shrines and meeting hall are obligatorical for community. But as told, your place, your merits and help for many to give it all a devoted and respectful touch.

Comment: Although maybe possible to simply starts such, for my person, it's better it you here take the oppotunity to make merits and high sacrifices. The Gems are fine anyway.

Comment: (as told, it didn't worked. Atma does not get any emails from Se-server and the given account by SE's management and owner might be still not verified or just temporary lack of proper connection, but really not so importand, Nyom Chris could move it there, if wishing)

Comment: A good approach is always not to think and argue why to stay at usual habits, but to try to be creative to make a different, make merits, in onse circumstances without harm someone. Those suggested topics are not thought as socialising places, but actually importand starters for a Buddhist community, very formal and liberating. Not chats... and their use, put actually opposite.

Comment: You, Nyom Chris, could of course (if in doubt), and it would be even proper, ask you community manager from the sites owner, about such, and my person thinks that they would possible even welcome such initiatives for good and special purposes. Normal users are not common with such, and westerns even lesser, so one can not expect much support from normal users of internet at the beginning but open up a door for them not so avaliable anywhere.

Comment: @SamanaJohann I'm not quite clear, sure, what you're asking for or suggesting -- e.g. I don't think I could explain it to someone else. Can you reference (link to) a good example of what kind of "online space" or "content" you're referring to? Sometimes seeing an example helps me to understand what's being talked about. I think this is primarily a Q+A site -- and is not a monastery -- and there are other places on the 'net, as you presumably know, for other types of conversation.

Comment: May person could only provide sangham.net, in western spheres is such unknown. Asians sometimes run such good samples, but they are seldom accessable. There are NO proper and given places avaliable on internet aside of this, as far as known. The only monastery who does such, the australians, they charge money form their visitors... But why not simple "he would like to make some community topics, such as a topic where people could introduce themselves, and a 'Shrine topic', where faithful followers could bow down and take refuge in Buddha, dhamma, sangha. Would such be ok for SE.", to bring..

Comment: ... a simple sample if wished. Again, your merits, your creativity and good to invite good monks, not cool, to assist you here. My person is not someone eager to lead and much  skilled for such community maintaining, as less interest, yet always open to give good advices to them who like for a good and in good ways.